# Can the sum of n positive integers be divided by each of the n numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

What are the possible values of $n>1$ such that there exists $n$ distinct positive integers with each of the $n$ numbers dividing the sum of the $n$ numbers?

I Just noticed that all $n>2$ are possible values. The proof is very simple and I overthought the question at the start

Comment: I wasn't sure of the answer so I didn't know what to do but huge thanks for telling me the result so I can try to work the proof out! Just noticed how people are very helpful and friendly on this site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just need to find one example for $n=3$ first. The smallest example is clearly $$1+2+3=6$$
Now, for $n>3$, just keep making the old sum your next number. For example, when $n=4$, you will have $1,2,3,6$, for $n=5$, you will have $1,2,3,6,12$ and so on. It is clear that all the numbers will divide your sum.

Essentially, for all $n > 3$, your numbers will be $1,2,3,6,6 \cdot 2, 6 \cdot 2^2 , 6 \cdot 2^3, \ldots, 6 \cdot 2^{n-4} $ for which your sum will be:
$$(1+2+3)+6(1+2+4+\ldots+2^{n-4})=6+6(2^{n-3}-1)=6 \cdot 2^{n-3}$$
and now, it is clear why each number divides the sum.

For $n=2$, there is no such pair since if your numbers are $a$ and $b$:
$$a \mid (a+b) \implies a \mid b \implies a \leqslant b$$
$$b \mid (a+b) \implies b \mid a \implies b \leqslant a$$
and clearly both these can hold true if and only if $a=b$ which contradicts the requirement that $a$ and $b$ are distinct.